# CloudFormation Transform::Include parameters

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I want to use AWS macro Transform::Include with some dynamic parameters for my file.

```
Resources:
  'Fn::Transform':
    Name: 'AWS::Include'
    Parameters:
      TestMacroVariable: 
        Default: 2
        Type: Number
      Location: !Sub "s3://${InstallBucketName}/test.yaml"
```

test.yaml:

```
DataAutoScalingGroup:
  Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
  Properties:
    LaunchConfigurationName: 
      Ref: DataLaunchConfiguration
    MinSize: '1'
    MaxSize: '100'
    DesiredCapacity: 
      Ref: TestMacroVariable
...
```

After calling:  `aws cloudformation describe-stack-events --stack-name $stack`

I get:

> "ResourceStatusReason": "The value of parameter TestMacroVariable
>   under transform Include must resolve to a string, number, boolean or a
>   list of any of these.. Rollback requested by user."

---

When I try to do it this way:

```
Resources:
  'Fn::Transform':
    Name: 'AWS::Include'
    Parameters:
      TestMacroVariable: 2
      Location: !Sub "s3://${InstallBucketName}/test.yaml"
```

I get:

> "ResourceStatusReason": "Template format error: Unresolved resource
>   dependencies [TestMacroVariable] in the Resources block of the
>   template"

Error is the same when I don't provide **TestMacroVariable** at all.

---

Tried with different types: String, Number, Boolean, List - none of them work.

Answer (score 2):

As i know you cannot have anything other than **Location** key in the `Parameters` section of the `AWS::Include`. Check here [AWS DOC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/create-reusable-transform-function-snippets-and-add-to-your-template-with-aws-include-transform.html)

Comment: `Location` is the only parameter listed in that documentation, but you can add any other parameter that your document expects. For example, if you are including a userdata document that expects two parameters `X` and `Y`, you can define `X` and `Y` in the `Parameters` section of `AWS::Include`.

Answer (score 0):

Building on what @BatteryAcid Said you can refer the parameters in your Cloudformation template directly from your file using Sub function:

In your CF template :

```
Parameters:
  TableName:
    Type: String
    Description: Table Name of the Dynamo DB Users table
    Default: 'Users'
```

In the file you are including:

```
     "Resource": [
      {
        "Fn::Sub": [
          "arn:${AWS::Partition}:dynamodb:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:table/${tableName}",
          {
            "tableName": {
              "Ref": "TableName"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

Alternatively doesn't have to be a parameter but any resource from your template :

```
Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${QueryTelemtryFunction.Arn}/invocations
```

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative, you can pass in the whole S3 path as a parameter and reference it in `Location`:

```
Parameters:
  MyS3Path:
    Type: String
    Default: 's3://my-cf-templates/my-include.yaml'  

...

'Fn::Transform':
  Name: 'AWS::Include'
  Parameters:
    Location: !Ref MyS3Path
```